# overloading ++ C#

Tags: operator-overloading

```
public static MyClass operator++(MyClass op)
{
    MyClass result = new MyClass(); // MyClass() x=y=z=0; 

    result.x = op.x + 1;
    result.y = op.y + 1;
    result.z = op.z + 1;

    return result:
}

//...

public void Main()
{
    MyClass c = new MyClass();
    MyClass b = new MyClass(1,2,3); //ctor x = 1, ...
    c = b++;
}
```

The question is why variable `b` going to change?
because `result.x = op.x + 1;` shouldn't change `op.x` 
result actually is `c` is `(1,2,3)` `b` is `(2,3,4)`
I don't understand why not `c` is `(2,3,4)` and `b` is `(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say, "because `result.x = op.x + 1` shouldn't change op.x."  But `++` is *not* the same as `+ 1`.  It is the standard postfix increment operator which increments the operand `b` by using your custom overload -- it assigns the new value to `b` immediately *after* passing the previous value to `c`.  If it were the prefix operator (`++b`), it would have incremented *before* passing the value to `c`.

Without any overloads at all, the code:

```
b++
```

Is equivalent to:

```
b = b + 1
```

And

```
c = b++
```

Is equivalent to:

```
c = b;
b = b + 1;
```

Now using your overload, it's more equivalent to:

```
c = b;
b = call_your_++_overload(b);
```

Comment: But "++" is overloaded when I use it here. "c = b++" So C# automatically adds non-overloaded functions from base "++"  ?

Comment: @Nikita, yes, it's overloaded -- so it's using your code; but the semantics are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Behaviour you are describing is according to the [documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx)

> postfix increment operation - The
>   result of the operation is the value
>   of the operand before it has been
>   incremented.

Both `b++` (postfix operator) and `++b` (prefix operator) changes original variable. To get desired results I would suggest overloading `+` operator and change `c = b++;` to `c = b + 1;`